# Call Listview onclick button

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I have to call my function to the click of the button. if in XML onclick event call (listaFatture) I get error. Why? Should I set in another class?

```
private void listaFatture(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = new FattureHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
    final List<Dettaglio> dettagli = new ArrayList<Dettaglio>();        

        String sql ="SELECT nome_fornitore, SUM(importo_fattura) FROM Fatture WHERE importo_fattura>0 GROUP BY nome_fornitore";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);          
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            Dettaglio d = new Dettaglio();

            d.fornitore = c.getString(0);
            d.totale = c.getFloat(1);


            dettagli.add(d);
        }
        c.close();  
    db.close();     
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Dettaglio>(this, R.layout.dettaglio_elenco_fatture_group, R.id.t_fornitore_group, dettagli){         
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);                    
            TextView tvFornitore, tvTotale;
            tvFornitore = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.t_fornitore_group);
            tvTotale = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.t_euro_group);


            Dettaglio d = dettagli.get(position);

            tvFornitore.setText(d.fornitore+"");
```

Logcat:

```
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method listaFatture()(View) in the activity class fatture.acquisti.Elenco_fatt_group for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button_1'
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3722)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4354)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17961)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: listaFatture() [class android.view.View]
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
09-21 15:29:09.617: E/AndroidRuntime(20670):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3715)
```

Comment: Can you please post the logcat with the error?

Comment: Can you post the code of your activity where you set the onclick event of your button. Also, in which class the method `listaFatture` is now declared?

Comment: I have not said no onclick event. I do not know how to do it I only added "listaFatture ()" onClick in the XML file. how should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your method as public and add the parameter:

```
public void listaFatture(View view){

    // the rest of the code as is

}
```

Comment: I get this error:
/AndroidRuntime(16488): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method listaFatture()(View) in the activity class fatture.acquisti.Elenco_fatt_group for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button_1'

E/AndroidRuntime(16488): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: listaFatture() [class android.view.View]
0E/AndroidRuntime(16488):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)